# @schematics/angular:library VS @nrwl/angular:library

Tags: javascript, angular, nrwl-nx

I want to add a new feature module to my existing angular app through the use of Nx Console tool, but I have been confused which of the following should I use to do so:

```
ng generate @schematics/angular:library
```

or

```
ng generate @nrwl/angular:library
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can use both of them.

The `@nrwl/angular:library` schematic [uses the `@schematics/angular:library` schematic under the hood](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/angular/src/generators/library/library.ts#L58) and adds some functionality around it including generating [publishable libraries](https://nx.dev/structure/buildable-and-publishable-libraries), adding [tags to the library](https://nx.dev/structure/buildable-and-publishable-libraries) or [out of the box jest support for testing](https://nx.dev/packages/jest#setting-up-jest).

See all configuration options here:

- [for the `@schematics/angular:library` schematic](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/schematics/angular/library/schema.json)
- [for the `@nrwl/angular:library` schematic](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/angular/src/generators/library/schema.json)

Additionally, in an Nx workspace it makes sense to use the `@nrwl` schematic, because it follows the standard structure of nx workspaces by placing the libraries in the libs folder by default.

*Note, that Nrwl uses the naming `generators` for `schematics`.*

Comment: Link for @schematics/angular:library schematic's schema :) should be this - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/schematics/angular/library/schema.json

Comment: @vlad2135 thanks for the hint. Seems I failed with copy-pasting the links. Adjusted the answer with your link.